How to properly read data from a stream with C++20 ranges library?
With C++20, new ranges library was introduced to present an alternative way to deal with sorts of sequences (rather than simple for/while cycles and <algorithm> approach with iterators).
It is idiomatically appealing to me because I sometimes definitely like to think of a container, or of a contiguous part of a container, or of an arithmetic progression as of one object rather than two (as in iterator approach) or more (as in cycle approach). Therefore I try to adapt my coding style to this new (well, not exactly, there is already C++23) feature of the language.
One thing I'm particularly interested in is reading from a stream. Suppose I have the following setup. I have my standard input stream with numbers 1 2 3 4 5 put into it. I would like to read first three numbers from it, put them in an array v of type std::array<int, 3>, then read one more number and put in into a variable n of type int. Certainly I expect v == [1, 2, 3] and n == 4.
With a simple cycle, this is quite straightforward (https://godbolt.org/z/q1czTqnoY):
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) std::cin >> v[i];
std::cin >> n;

With an iterator approach, there is also quite a neat way to do it: convert std::cin to an iterator over an int sequence, and copy values from this sequence to v:
std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), 3, v.begin());
std::cin >> n;

This produces the expected result v == [1, 2, 3], n == 4: https://godbolt.org/z/qhc5EfcPh.
Now I want to do the same thing with ranges.
The problem is I constantly get, without any reason I was able to recognize, the result v == [1, 2, 3], n == 5, as if during the phase of reading v it read and discarded an extra number 4. Approaches that I tried:

simply adding ::ranges to the previous example (https://godbolt.org/z/qoe7b64e6):
std::ranges::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), 3, v.begin());
std::cin >> n;


replacing std::istream_iterator with its modern alternative, which is view (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/basic_istream_view) (but still taking .begin() of it), and copying from it (https://godbolt.org/z/h489eEnxM):
std::ranges::copy_n(std::views::istream<int>(std::cin).begin(), 3, v.begin());
std::cin >> n;


using std::views::istream, but instead of copy_n first apply take (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/take_view) adaptor (https://godbolt.org/z/b1bjKEPY1):
std::ranges::copy(std::views::istream<int>(std::cin) | std::ranges::views::take(3), v.begin());
std::cin >> n;



What is even more catastrophic to me is that, if instead of 3 I try and read zero elements from std::istream, now only for cycle works correctly and ends up with v == [0, 0, 0], n == 1 result (https://godbolt.org/z/T13Kdjozh), the rest of them keep giving me v == [0, 0, 0], n == 2!

https://godbolt.org/z/GrnrTsMcd

https://godbolt.org/z/orf69PYG1

https://godbolt.org/z/bY8TqGv8K


I will say for myself that these antics completely discourage the desire to use std::ranges. It is bitter for me to say this, because I love C++ and want to use its new features so that both the clarity of the code and the intuitive clarity of the effect it produces grow.
But just in case I've got it all wrong: is it possible to use std::ranges to read data from streams idiomatically and reliably? Is there a manual that spells this out (I couldn't find a spec on cppreference that would imply the aforementioned special effects)? And would we have to handle the null case separately anyway, even in the iterator approach?

You are encountering a classic issue with views::istream in C++20 ranges. One alternative is to get the next element through the iterator returned by ranges::copy_n.

But what to do if the type of n differs from the type of the elements of v?
